Updating a variable in Room database using the UPDATE statement
I have a program that works on two devices for transferring files broken into parts, when sending from one device to another, for example, a picture, the number of bytes is received in the count variable, then I am going to connect the progressbar, the problem is saving the values, for example if the file weighs 20 kilobytes, I receive 20,000 parts, which I save using the update method, that is, I take a variable in the database and add new values ​​to it at each iteration, in theory, progress should reach 100%, however, the update method does not saves some values ​​from iterations, simply skipping them without saving, subsequently the progressbar value does not reach 100%, what am I missing?
Dao:
@Query("UPDATE FileItem SET progressDownload = :value WHERE uuid = :uuid")
suspend fun updateProgressDownload(uuid: String, value: Long)

RepositoryImpl:
override suspend fun updateProgressDownload(uuid: String, value: Long) {
    fileDao.updateProgressDownload(uuid, value)
}

View Model:
val currentValueDataBase =
roomRepository.getItemByUuid(it)?.progressDownload
val addANewValueToThePrevious = currentValueDataBase?.plus(transport.count)
    if (addANewValueToThePrevious != null) {
       roomRepository.updateProgressDownload(it, addANewValueToThePrevious)
}

This is the log:


You haven’t shown the code that calls the ViewModel code you shared, but I’m guessing you haven’t done anything to make sure it cannot be called multiple times in parallel?

I didn’t take into account the moment of calling the function in parallel, but now I fixed everything using private val addSaveItemMutex = Mutex() and called addSaveItemMutex.withLock { in my method, – Tenfour04 thank you very much! Please post your answer so I can accept it
